# Embedding youtube channels in android application

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

I want to be able to display a certain youtube channel's videos and allow the user to select one of their videos to watch. Do I have to do this manually (parse the source code of the webpage to get each individual video link and then display them) or can I use the youtube api?

If anyone has done this, example code or tutorials would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it? I too want to implement this in my app.

Answer (score 2):

you can do that without parse any webpage, the correct way is using the youtube api

from a Youtube video get the Id
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**opZ69P-0Jbc**

(this is the mobile youtube version
http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=**opZ69P-0Jbc**)

so you can get the data scheme
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/**opZ69P-0Jbc**

and you can get for example the related videos
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/**opZ69P-0Jbc**/related

**heres the youtube api reference**
http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html